# Solving Higher-Order Non-Homogeneous ODE $y'''-3y''+3y'-y=24(x+1)e^{x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Given equation:

$$y'''-3y''+3y'-y=24(x+1)e^x$$ with initial values $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=2$ and $y''(0)=7$

I get the homogeneous equation as $(c_1+c_2x+c_3x^{2})e^{x}$

But I don't get how to get the particular solution as it is written $24(x+1)e^{x}$

Comment: You have to find $A,B$ such that $y=(Ax^4+Bx^3)e^x$ is a solution.

Comment: I am confused how you got your homogeneous solution to look like that. $x^3-3x^2-1$ doesn't have $1$ as a root.

Comment: Of course, that's provided you have a correct solution to the homogeneous equation, which seems not to be the case.

Comment: Are you a homework poster?

Comment: Have you left out a $3y'$ term in the equation?

Comment: Indeed if it is supposed to be $y'''-3y''+3y'-y$ then that would explain things. In that the particular solution would be of the form $x^3(Ax+B)e^x$, since $1$ would be a triple root of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @GerryMyerson how did you get to know $y=(Ax^{4}+Bx^{3})e^{x}$

Comment: @Santi Because the coefficient in the exponent in the forcing is $1$ which is a triple root of the characteristic polynomial, so the form of the particular solution is $x^3 p(x) e^x$ where $p$ is a polynomial of the degree appearing in the forcing ($1$ in this case).

Comment: @Santi One way to look at this is basically that anything in the homogeneous solution shouldn't contribute to the particular solution. (It *can* but it doesn't have to.) So say we assume that the particular solution is going to be of the form $q(x) e^x$ for some polynomial $q$ (which is reasonable, since the image of a function of this type under a linear constant coefficient differential operator is another function of this type).

Comment: @Santi (Cont.) To exclude terms appearing in the homogeneous solution, $q$ can only contain terms of degree at least $3$.  Since your original right side had a linear polynomial in it, there are "two coefficients to match", so $q$ should contain at least two terms, and "unless something weird happened", exactly two terms would suffice as well. It turns out that "something weird" never happens.

Comment: Don't you have any study materials, Santi? A textbook, some lecture notes? The form of the particular solution is something that's discussed in some detail in every exposition of these diferential equations – are you sure you haven't got access to some thing that lays out the forms to use?

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is explained very briefly about it. I will find some notes and studies to study it in detail.

Answer (score 1):

**Easy way:**
$$y'''-3y''+3y'-y=24(x+1)e^x$$
$$(ye^{-x})'''=24(x+1)$$
Integrate three times.

---

**Another way:**
$$y'''-3y''+3y'-y=24(x+1)e^x$$
The poynomial characteristic is:
$$r^3-3r^2+3r-1=0 \implies (r-1)^3$$
The solution to the homogeneous equation is
$$y_h=c_1e^x+c_2xe^x+c_3x^2e^x$$
For the particular solution try:
$$y_p=x^3(Ax+B)e^x$$

Answer (score 0):

By solving homogeneous solution and particular solution I get the final solution as:

$$(1+x+x^{2})e^{x}+(x^{4}+4x^{3})e^{x}$$

Answer (score -3):

$$\frac{1}{f(D)} \left ( e^{ax} \phi(x) \right ) = e^{ax} \left ( \frac{1}{f(D+a)} \phi(x) \right )$$

The formula above would be of help to solve the particular integral $$\int 24 x(e^x)\,dx.$$

Comment: That integral is very far from a solution to the problem.

Comment: That formula says, for this problem, that $\frac{1}{(D-1)^3} \left ( e^x \phi(x) \right ) = e^x \left ( \frac{1}{D^3} \phi(x) \right )$. This can be used to find the particular solution without using a method like undetermined coefficients, but it still requires you to do some integrals (three in fact, not one).